# Retrieve multiple data from sql database and print individual lines for each using php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm having 2 database I have successfully retrieved the data from SQL database using php. But I don't know how to join and print individual messages using php

Customer

| ID | product id |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 202201 |
| 02 | 202103 |
| 03 | 202204 |
| 03 | 202204 |

Product

| product id | product |
| --- | --- |
| 202201 | phone. |
| 202103 | monitor. |
| 202204 | laptop. |
| 202204 | desktop. |

Current Output in sql

| ID | product |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | phone |
| 02 | monitor |
| 03 | laptop |
| 03 | desktop |

Current Output in php

01 - phone
02 - monitor
03 - laptop, desktop

**Expected Output in PHP**

**If 1 product**

Your Id is 01 the product is phone.

**If 2 product**

Your Id is 03 the products are laptop and desktop.

**My code**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, product FROM customer a, product b WHERE a.product_id = b.product_id ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $id[] = $row[“id”];
    $product[] = $row[“product”];

    $max = sizeof($product);
    $max_m = sizeof($id);

if($product[$i] == 3)
{
  $msg= “Your Id is $id the products are $product[0], $product[1] and $product[2] ”;
}
elseif ($product[$i] == 2)
{
  $msg = “Your Id is $id the products are $product[0] and $product[1]”;
}
elseif($product[$i] == 1)
{
  $msg = “Your Id is $id the product is $product[0]”;
}

}

for($i=0; $i<$max_m;$i++)
{
if(!isset($duplicate_m[$id$i]]))
 {
  $duplicate_m[$id[$i]] = $msisdn[$i] = $product[$i];
 }
else
 {
  $duplicate_m[$id[$i]] .= ", {$product[$i]}";
 }


}
echo $msg;
print_r($duplicate_m);

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You never seem to output $msg anywhere

Comment: My output is in an array I can't get seem to get the output msg

Comment: Of course it might be that $msg contains nothing because it never goes into the if statements which generate it. Have you done any debugging? Those statements rely on $i (e.g.  $product[$i] == 3) but I don't see $i declared anywhere. And also the "product" column contains a string so I'm not sure why you're trying to compare (parts of) it to a number. Its quite difficult to see what the logic was supposed to be in that area

Comment: Perhaps you intended to compare it to the "product id" column instead?